# Docker + Airflow (Some tasks remains on "scheduled" forever)

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm using Docker to run/test airflow DAGs locally, before I release changes to production. For whatever reason, some DAGs (=the first task) remain forever on "scheduled", while others work perfectly fine. There is an interesting pattern: Smaller DAGs seem to run every now and then, while bigger DAGs with many simultaneous tasks always remain scheduled.

When I click on the "scheduled" task and go to "Instance Details", then I can see this message: ('Not scheduling since there are %s open slots in pool %s and require %s pool slots', -1, 'dbrelay', 1)

Does anyone know whats going on here?

Thank you in advance!!!

Ps. This problem has never ocured in production, only locally
[image]

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2022, 2, 18),
    "email": ["xxx@xxx.de"],
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "on_failure_callback": task_fail_slack_alert,  # slack alert on all task failures
    "location": "eu",
    "bigquery_conn_id": BIGQUERY_CONN_ID,
    "provide_context": True,
}

with DAG(
    "dag_name",
    default_args=default_args,
    concurrency=3,  concurrent tasks
    catchup=False,  
    schedule_interval="30 05,17 * * *", 
    max_active_runs=1,
    params={
        "PROJECT": PROJECT,
        "TMP_VIEW_DATASET": TMP_VIEW_DATASET,
        "HOURS_TO_SUBTRACT": 4,
        "REPORT_DATE": REPORT_DATE,
    },
) as dag:


with TaskGroup(group_id="dbrelays") as tg_dbrelays:

        for index, relay in enumerate(dbrelays):

            op_dbrelay = EPBigQueryInsertJobOperator(
                task_id=f"db_relay_{relay}",
                sql="templates/generic/create_or_replace_snapshot.sql",
                pool="dbrelay",  
                params={
                    "SOURCE_PROJECT": PROJECT,
                    "DESTINATION_PROJECT": PROJECT,
                    "SOURCE_DATASET": "dbrelay",
                    "DESTINATION_DATASET": TMP_VIEW_DATASET,
                    "TABLE": relay,
                },
            )
```

Comment: Is the task configured to use a specific pool? And does that pool exist on your Airflow docker deployment?

Comment: yes, the pool is called dbrelay and has 2 slots (increasing the slots doesn't) help. The only place where defined this pools is directly in Airflow > Admin > pools. Then I referenced this pool in specific tasks - example:

    with TaskGroup(group_id="dbrelays") as tg_dbrelays:

        for index, relay in enumerate(dbrelays):

            op_dbrelay = EPBigQueryInsertJobOperator(
                task_id=f"db_relay_{relay}",
                sql="templates/generic/xxxxxx.sql",
                pool="dbrelay",  # limit concurrency via a pool)

Comment: Which version are you using? Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14515) that has been fixed in 2.1.1. If it's not your case please update your question with the details of the deployment and the DAG code, so it will be easier to investigate the problem

Comment: @vinsce I provided you the core code of the DAG and task group which is affected. Unfortunately I can't provide the entire code of the setup as it's part of a massive Airflow project. The only way possible would be to clone the repo, but that's not an option due to security aspects.

Docker version: 20.10.17 / Airflow: 2.2.3